# How to create a costomized JSONArray From a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Consider a JSONArray like the following:

```
String str = "[{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1520160581613,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"taskmanager1:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"taskmanager1:8042","HostName":"taskmanager1"},{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1519852956106,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"datanode2:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"datanode2:8042","HostName":"datanode2"},{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1520160582267,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"taskmanager3:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"taskmanager3:8042","HostName":"taskmanager3"},{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1519852951525,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"datanode3:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"datanode3:8042","HostName":"datanode3"},{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1520160582259,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"taskmanager2:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"taskmanager2:8042","HostName":"taskmanager2"},{"NodeManagerVersion":"2.8.3","Rack":"/default-rack","LastHealthUpdate":1519852955648,"HealthReport":"","State":"RUNNING","NodeId":"datanode1:45454","NodeHTTPAddress":"datanode1:8042","HostName":"datanode1"}]"

JSONArray hostsTemp = new JSONArray(str)
                JSONArray res = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject temp ;
                for (Object t : hostsTemp) {
                    temp = new JSONObject(t.toString());
                    res.put( "{HostName:" + temp.get("HostName") + "," + "State:" + temp.get("State") + "}");
                }
```

It contains many extra data and I want to create a new JSONArray with just two keys, `HostName` and `State` of every element. Is there any way more efficient than my solution to do that?

Comment: your example does not compile. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example